# SharedPreferences returning empty string

Tags: android

In my LoginActivity I'm setting a preference to identify the user is logged in and then I switch to the WelcomeActivity.

```
            Log.v("onPostExecute", "Login successful");
            // save login session in SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("email", email);
            editor.commit();

            Intent welcomeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(welcomeIntent);
```

In my launcher activity (RegisterActivity) I'm checking in `onCreate` for possible settings, so that the user is redirect automatically.

```
    // redirect to welcomeActivity if user is logged in
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("EMAIL", 0);
    String email = settings.getString("email", "");
    if (!email.isEmpty()) {
        Intent welcomeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(welcomeIntent);           
    }
```

email is always empty, so the user, who logged in before and restarted the app is not automatically redirected. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are writing in two different files

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", 0);
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("EMAIL", 0);
```

those two line will create two different xml files, one called LOGIN and the other EMAIL

Answer (score 1):

In `LoginActivity` you're using "LOGIN":

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", 0);
```

In `RegisterActivity` you're using "EMAIL":

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("EMAIL", 0);
```

Use the same on both

Answer (score 1):

because this

```
getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", 0);
```

is not this

```
getSharedPreferences("EMAIL", 0);
```

you are using 2 different sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", 0);
```

with this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and use same name to get it Like

Replace this line

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("EMAIL", 0);
```

with this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", MODE_PRIVATE);
```